How set the widget size to fit all the width and height of the main window?
I'm trying to make a small app in Tkinter, and I want to insert a notebook after a connection inside my main window.
But I don't find how I can make to set the notebook's size to the fit full width and height of the window.
Here my code:
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *


class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        #on définit le titre de la page
        self.title("Youtube Manager")
        self.state("zoomed")
        # self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.login = ttk.Label(bootstyle="primary",text="Login :")
        self.login_input = ttk.Entry(bootstyle="primary",width=30)

        self.pwd = ttk.Label(bootstyle="primary",text="Mot de passe :")
        self.pwd_input = ttk.Entry(bootstyle="primary",width=30)

        self.btn_connect = ttk.Button(bootstyle="success",text="Connexion")

        self.separator = ttk.Separator(bootstyle="primary",orient="horizontal")

        #on place les widget
        self.login.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=2,pady=1)
        self.login_input.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2)

        self.pwd.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=2,pady=1)
        self.pwd_input.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=2,pady=10)

        self.btn_connect.grid(row=0,column=4,columnspan=2,padx=2)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self,bootstyle="primary")
        self.notebook.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='NSWE',rowspan=5,columnspan=50)

Result
Expected

I would suggest to put those label, entry and button widgets in a frame.  Then use pack() on the frame, separator and notebook:
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Youtube Manager")
        #self.state("zoomed")
        self.geometry("1000x600")

        # frame for those label, entry and button widgets
        top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        top_frame.pack(fill='x')

        self.login = ttk.Label(top_frame, bootstyle="primary", text="Login :")
        self.login_input = ttk.Entry(top_frame, bootstyle="primary", width=30)
        self.pwd = ttk.Label(top_frame, bootstyle="primary", text="Mot de passe :")
        self.pwd_input = ttk.Entry(top_frame, bootstyle="primary", width=30)
        self.btn_connect = ttk.Button(top_frame, bootstyle="success", text="Connexion")

        self.login.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=1)
        self.login_input.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2)
        self.pwd.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2, pady=1)
        self.pwd_input.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=2, pady=10)
        self.btn_connect.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2, padx=2)

        self.separator = ttk.Separator(self, bootstyle="primary", orient="horizontal")
        self.separator.pack(fill="x")

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self, bootstyle="primary")
        self.notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=1, padx=2, pady=2)

MainApp().mainloop()

Note that it is better to specify the parent for those widgets.
Result:

